# Rotation angle in transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have four points in 3d space. let's say p1 to p4. I want to perform 4 rotation matrices on these points:

1. moving p1 to the center (it works well)
2. rotating over x axis so that p2(z)==0.
3. rotating over v12 vector (vector from p1 to p2) so that p3(z)==0
4. rotating over z axis so that p2(x)==0.

The problem is that in rotation steps, I can't find a solution that works for all rotations. For some angles I need to use -angle, for some the angle, for some pi-angle, and so on. I was thinking to divide angles from 0-90,90-180,and so on. but it doesn't work either.

example:

For step 3, I get the angle between the p1,p2,p3 plane, with xy plane.

```
normal_p = np.cross(v12,v13,axis=0).T
normal_xy = np.array([[0,0,1]]).T
angle = np.arccos(normal_p.dot(normal_xy)/(np.linalg.norm(normal_p)*np.linalg.norm(normal_xy)))[0][0]

rotation_angle = angle
```

Then I rotate using this matrix (Rodrigues):

```
v12 = p2 - p1
u = v12/np.linalg.norm(v12)
ux = u[0][0]
uy = u[1][0]
uz = u[2][0]
c = math.cos(rotation_angle)
s = math.sin(rotation_angle)

t3 = np.array([
    [c+(1-c)*(ux**2),(ux*uy*(1-c))-(uz*s),(uy*s)+(ux*uz*(1-c)),0],
    [(uz*s)+(ux*uy*(1-c)), c+((1-c)*(uy**2)),(-ux*s)+(uy*uz*(1-c)),0],
    [(-uy*s)+(ux*uz*(1-c)), (ux*s)+(uy*uz*(1-c)), c+((1-c)*(uz**2)),0],
    [0,0,0,1]
])

p1 = np.dot(t3,p1)
p2 = np.dot(t3,p2)
p3 = np.dot(t3,p3)
p4 = np.dot(t3,p4)
```

When angle is 89.56:

```
# from:
[[0. 0. 0. 1.]]
[[-1.0857  2.1951  0.      1.    ]]
[[-0.5377  1.0493  2.1843  1.    ]]
[[-1.8203  0.3984  0.6827  1.    ]]
 # to (when rotation_angle = angle)
 [[0. 0. 0. 1.]]
 [[-1.0857  2.1951  0.      1.    ]]
 [[1.4351 2.025  0.0335 1.    ]]
 [[0.0858 1.3412 1.4602 1.    ]]
 # To (when rotation_angle = -angle)
[[0. 0. 0. 1.]]
[[-1.0857  2.1951  0.      1.    ]]
[[-2.4806  0.0883  0.      1.    ]]
[[-1.138   0.7358 -1.4497  1.    ]]
```

when angle = 54.01

```
# from:
[[0. 0. 0. 1.]]
[[-2.2648  1.0206  0.      1.    ]]
[[-1.6398 -0.6844 -1.7866  1.    ]]
[[-0.7915  1.1338 -1.3961  1.    ]]
# To (when rotation_angle = angle)
[[0. 0. 0. 1.]]
[[-2.2648  1.0206  0.      1.    ]]
[[-2.0139 -1.5145 -0.      1.    ]]
[[-1.3756 -0.1624 -1.3937  1.    ]]
# To (when rotation_angle = -angle)
[[0. 0. 0. 1.]]
[[-2.2648  1.0206  0.      1.    ]]
[[-0.8261  1.1213 -2.0999  1.    ]]
[[-0.4474  1.8973 -0.2472  1.    ]]
```

So you see that -angle works for the first case and doesn't work for the second case and vice versa. I want something that works for both and can't understand why it doesn't work, even though both angles are in the range of 0-90.

Comment: this isn't a math question but more of a programming question. better to try stack overflow